# Enter all data from Table(T2) insert in Table(T1) against each row T1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have T1 Table which have 3 column date, id, name I Have other table T2 which have ID, Name I want put all data of T2 in T1 agt each date like this

```
           T1                               T2               Required output of T1
DATE          ID       NAME     || ID           NAME   ||DATE        ID    NAME 
02/16/21                        || 100          Shaun  ||02/16/21    100   Shaun
02/15/21                        || 101          Alex   ||02/16/21    101   Alex
02/14/21                        || 102          Scott  ||02/16/21    102   Scott
```

it will repeat for each date any one please help and commit in T1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks as if you want to **cross join** these two tables.

Currently, you have this:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

DATUM              ID NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
02/16/2021
02/15/2021
02/14/2021

SQL> select * from t2;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
       100 Shaun
       101 Alex
       102 Scott
```

Output you want:

```
SQL> select a.datum, b.id, b.name
  2  from t1 a cross join t2 b
  3  order by a.datum, b.id;

DATUM              ID NAME
---------- ---------- -----
02/14/2021        100 Shaun
02/14/2021        101 Alex
02/14/2021        102 Scott
02/15/2021        100 Shaun
02/15/2021        101 Alex
02/15/2021        102 Scott
02/16/2021        100 Shaun
02/16/2021        101 Alex
02/16/2021        102 Scott

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you wanted to populate `t1` table with such a result, I'd say that the simplest option is to do it in two steps: `insert` + `delete`:

- first insert result of the cross join
- then delete rows whose `id` is empty

Something like this:

```
SQL> insert into t1 (datum, id, name)
  2  select a.datum, b.id, b.name
  3  from t1 a cross join t2 b;

9 rows created.

SQL> delete from t1 where id is null;

3 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from t1;

DATUM              ID NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
02/16/2021        100 Shaun
02/16/2021        101 Alex
02/16/2021        102 Scott
02/15/2021        100 Shaun
02/15/2021        101 Alex
02/15/2021        102 Scott
02/14/2021        100 Shaun
02/14/2021        101 Alex
02/14/2021        102 Scott

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```